# Synchronized conditional statement in Go

Tags: go, synchronization

I have a method that may be used in multiple goroutines and run concurrently.

Inside this method, I have a conditional statement. If the conditional statement is true, I want all other goroutines calling this method to wait for  **one and only one** of the goroutines to execute this conditional statement before proceeding to the next section.

For example:

```golang
type SomeClass struct {
    mu     sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SomeClass) SomeFunc() {
    //Do some calculation
    
    if condition {
        //This part should be executed by only one goroutine if the condition is true. 
        //All others must wait for this to finish
    }
    
    //Additional calculations
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```golang
func main(){
//initilize 


go someClass.SomeFunc()

//If the condition is true, the following will wait at the conditional statement until the first one finishes the code inside the conditional block
//Once it's done, they can run concurrently 
go someClass.SomeFunc()
go someClass.SomeFunc()
}
```

**Edit**
This is perhaps not the right design for this so I'm looking for any suggestions on how to implement this.

**Edit2:**
Note that each routine will have its own condition. This value of `condition` is not shared between threads. However, the work inside the condition should run only once only if the condition in 2 or more routines happens to be true at the same time.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You have a mutex, and only one caller can hold the mutex which is the behavior you describe. Have you tried using the mutex?

Comment: @JimB The issue is if the lock is placed inside the if statement, then all the routines will go inside that block, which is not what I want. And if the lock is outside the if statement, then all routines will wait for the lock there and proceed one at a time even if the statement is false. This is not what I want either. I want to ensure that the if statement is executed by the first routine only if the condtion is true, once that's done (or if the condition is false) then all routines can run in parallel.

Comment: So you release the lock when you want them to continue concurrently once you know it's same to do so.

Comment: have a look at https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#NewCond and https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond.Signal

Comment: What you describe maybe `sync.Once` would be ideal. It ensures the function is executed only once, and all goroutines will wait for it to complete.

Comment: @icza the reason I cannot use `sync.Once` is because the condition might change at runtime. If that happens, then it will need to be executed again when the function is called sometime later.

Comment: When the condition changes, you can create a new `sync.Once` value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The other answers to this question were incorrect because they do not satisfy the requirements of the question.

If the lock is added outside the conditional statement, then it will act as a barrier and will force all routines to synchronize at that spot. This is not the point of this question. Suppose resolving the condition value takes a long time, we do not want to check the value one routine at a time. We want to let every process check the condition at once so if the condition is false, we can move forward without stopping.

We want to ensure that the goroutines run in parallel if the condition is not true. Adding a lock inside the method and outside the conditional statement will not allow that to happen.

The following solutions are correct and passed all tests and performed well.

**Solution 1:**

Use 2 nested conditional statement such as this:

Note that in this case, if the condition is false, no lock will be called and no synchronization is needed. Everything can run in parallel.

```golang
type SomeClass struct {
    conditionMu sync.Mutex
    rwMu        sync.RWMutex
    additionalWorkRequired bool
}

func (c *SomeClass) SomeFunc() {
    //Do some work ...
    //Note: The condition is not shared, some routines can have false and some true at the same time, which is fine.
    condition := true;

    // All routines can check this condition and go inside the block if the condition is true
    if condition {
        c.rwMutex.Lock()
        c.additionalWorkRequired = true
        c.rwMutex.Unlock()

        //Lock so other routines can wait here for the first one
        c.conditionMu.Lock()
    
        if c.additionalWorkRequired {
             // Synchronous code goes here.
             c.additionalWorkRequired = false
        }

        //Unlock so all other processors can move forward in parallel 
        c.conditionMu.unlock()
       
    }

   //Finish up the remaining work

}
```

**Solution 2:**

Use the `do` function from [sync/singleflight](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) which can handle this situation automatically.

From documentation:

> Do executes and returns the results of the given function, making sure that only one execution is in-flight for a given key at a time. If a duplicate comes in, the duplicate caller waits for the original to complete and receives the same results. The return value shared indicates whether v was given to multiple callers.

**Edit:**

Since many seem to be confused by this question and answer, I'm adding a use case which might make things more clear:

```
1. Send a HTTP Request 
2. If the server returns an error saying credentials are incorrect (This is condition):
       2.1. Save current credentials in a local variable 
       2.2. Acquire the mutex lock
             2.2.1. Compare the shared credentials with the ones in the local variable(This is the second condition)
             If they are the same, then replace them with new ones
            
       2.3. Unlock
       2.4. Retry request
```

Comment: if `condition` is never protected my a mutex, how can it safely change state when multiple readers and writers are actively working with it ? I did not understand your code.

Comment: I think the use of RW locks is actually correct, but you're using it wrong. Before your `if(condition)` you need to acquire the `RLock()`, that will prevent all other code from entering while you have acquired your "write" lock inside that condition. You don't need your bool at all.

Comment: In fact, `condition` is not shared between routines, it's an independent value. The additional work just ensures that the condition will be false for all routines *next time* the function is called. Suppose we are want to send a value in the header to a server, the server tells us the data is expired and we need new data in the headers. We update the data once so when the function is recalled, the correct header will be sent by all routines.

Comment: @mh-cbon please see added use case under the answer which might make it more clear. I noticed the question was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a mutex protecting the condition from concurrent read/writes, and then a method for resetting the condition when you wish to execute the synchronous code again.

```golang
type SomeClass struct {
    conditionMu sync.Mutex
    condition   bool
}

func (c *SomeClass) SomeFunc() {
    // Lock the mutex, so that concurrent calls to SomeFunc will wait here.
    c.conditionMu.Lock()
    if c.condition {
        // Synchronous code goes here.

        // Reset the condition to false so that any waiting goroutines won't run the code inside this block again.
        c.condition = false
    }
    
    // Unlock the mutex, and any waiting goroutines.
    c.conditionMu.Unlock()
}

// ResetCondition sets the stored condition to true in a thread-safe manner.
func (c *SomeClass) ResetCondition() {
    c.conditionMu.Lock()
    c.condition = true
    c.conditionMu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: This will force all routines to sync above condition and proceed one at a time, even if the condition is false. Please see my answer below which seems to solve this issue.

Comment: @Aiden: no this will block all until the condition is met, then they can proceed concurrently after the conditional block, which is exactly what you asked for: _"I want all other goroutines calling this method to wait for one and only one of the goroutines to execute this conditional statement before proceeding to the next section"_. If you actually need a second condition like in your answer (although what you have is likely to lead to a data race on `condition`), that's fine, but this code is correct according to the stated specification.

Comment: Just to clarify this for others who may run into this question: The condition value is not shared between the routines, so there's no need to acquire the lock before checking for condition. We are only concerned with checking to see if the code inside the condition has run at least once if two or more threads happen to have a true condition around the same time. For this reason, the accepted answer works.